# UITableview with UITextField in tableHeaderView - canEditRowAtIndexPath not responding

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextfield` in my `tableHeaderView`. When I click the edit button in my navigation-bar, I can edit this textfield, but the rows of table below can't be edited/moved.

If I comment out the tableHeaderView with the TextField I can edit the rows without any problem?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    txt.text = @"header";
    txt.enabled =TableView.editing;
    return txt;
}

-(IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender{
    if (TableView.editing) {
        TableView.editing = NO;
    }else TableView.editing = YES;
    [TableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thx priyanka, but I put my TextField into the self.tableView.tableHeaderView, not into the section header. I didn't want to go through the hassle of creating a separate section with one row, only for my textfield. Not sure if I can do it that way?

Comment: I "solved" it, by adding a section with one row. Thought it should be possible using the tableHeaderView.